# Issue with edge cases in Quicksort C++

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort, partition

I'm writing a program for a class that requires I sort a list of strings representing decimal numbers. I converted the first 19 digits of each string to `unsigned long long`, and left the remaining digits as `string`'s, for use only if two `unsigned long long`'s matched exactly. After converting the strings to `unsigned long long`, I performed a quicksort on them. The quicksort works really well, except for two values that are out of place in the final sorted list. Does anyone notice a problem in my code that might cause this?

```
 int partition(int bottom, int top, unsigned long long pivot, string lastDigits)
{
    int left = bottom;
    int right = top;
    Number tmp;

    while (left <= right)
    {
        while(pivot < num[right].firstDigits || pivot == num[right].firstDigits && lastDigits < num[right].lastDigits)
        {
            right--;
        }

        while(pivot > num[left].firstDigits || pivot == num[left].firstDigits && lastDigits > num[left].lastDigits)
        {
            left++;
        }

        if(left <= right)
        {
            tmp = num[right];
            num[right]= num[left];
            num[left]=tmp;
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    return left;
}


void quickSort(int left, int right)
{
    unsigned long long pivot = num[(left+right)/2].firstDigits;
    int pivotpt;

    if(right > left)
    {
        pivotpt = partition(left, right, pivot, num[(left+right)/2].lastDigits);
        quickSort(left, pivotpt - 1);
        quickSort(pivotpt + 1, right);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you give us the list? More precisely, could you give us the shortest list that produces the error?

Comment: There are couple of things which aren't correct where you are not checking for lowerbound of right inside the following inner-loop

    while (pivot < num[right].firstDigits
           || (pivot == num[right].firstDigits
         && lastDigits < num[right].lastDigits)) {
      right--;
    }

Note that when pivot is the least value possible then without a bound validation right will go less than left and in worst case less than bottom.

additionally same thing for the next inner-loop where left is also not bounded, which will cause issue when pivot is the max value possible.